# Episerver TinyMCE plugin not working after EPI Server 8 upgradation

Tags: tinymce, episerver

I have implemented a custom tinymce plugin and before epi server up-gradation and it work fine. (In episever 7.5)

After the upgrade in edit mood when i load the editor it says:

```
"Failed to load: /util/Editor/tinymce/plugins/accordion/editor_plugin.js?moduleArea=Util".
```

In this other inbuilt plugins are working fine. Only manual implemented plugin arise this 404 error.

Also it failed to load its icon.

So i have added virtual path in web config and worked fine. But i need to fix this issue without adding virtual path. Any help for this ?

referred articles - http://world.episerver.com/documentation/Items/Tech-Notes/EPiServer-CMS-6/EPiServer-CMS-60/TinyMCE-Developers-Guide/

Comment: Where was your plugin located when working before upgrade?

Answer (score 0):

If you by

> But i need to fix this issue without adding virtual path.

mean that you do not have a js file that needs to be loaded you can add **ServerSideOnly = true**

```
[TinyMCEPluginNonVisual(
    PlugInName = "ExtendedValidElements",
    AlwaysEnabled = true,
    EditorInitConfigurationOptions = "{ extended_valid_elements: 'style' }",
    ServerSideOnly = true)]
public class ExtendedValidElements { }
```

That way no request for

```
/util/Editor/tinymce/plugins/[PlugInName]/editor_plugin.js
```

will be made.

Ref: http://cjsharp.com/blog/2013/04/15/how-to-add-valid-elements-like-iframes-to-tinymce-in-episerver-7/#disqus_thread